# Añadir columna a una tabla con JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Necesito ayuda, necesito insertar una columna en el `<thead>` mediante un botón con JavaScript, en una tabla:

```js
var cont = 0;
function agregar() {
    cont++;
    var html = "<th scope='col'>Nota 2</th>";
    $('#contenedor').append(html);
}
```

Tengo este código, pero solo me inserta un `<th>` después de la última fila y necesito agregar una columna.

Comment: Puedes poner la parte de la table del código HTML? AL menos desde el elemento `#contenedor`. En cualquier caso, el método `append` lo que hace es añadir al final del elemento HTML, por eso te sale al final.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres usar `append`, tienes que usarlo en el elemento `tr` dentro del elemento `th`. Porque `append` añade el HTML al final del elemento.

```js
let cont = 0;
const $filaTitulos = $('thead tr');

function agregar() {
    cont++;
    const numero = $filaTitulos.children().length + 1;
    const html = `<th>Titulo ${numero}</th>`;
    $filaTitulos.append(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Titulo 1</th>
      <th>Titulo 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cuerpo 1</td>
      <td>Cuerpo 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="agregar()">Agregar TH</button>
```

Si quieres añadir también al `tbody`, la idea es la misma, tienes que hacer `append` a cada `tr` dentro de `tbody`.